# Where in sql command optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-mobile-services

Hi there i am developing an application (on Azure mobile service to IOS) that user see products one by one , and i dont want to show user the products that he/she already seen so that i am logging everytime they see any product and i am showing products randomly however the command execution time is exponentially growing , it first executes the command in 1-2 seconds if the products_log table is empty however after adding logs to our log table and call the command it executes in 3+ sec and everytime i add more and more logs it grows exponentially until it gives timeout

Here is my command:

```
select TOP 50 * from products where id not in (select product_id from products_log where user_id = ?) and gender in (?,2) order by newid()
```

Here is an timeout exception that i am getting from azure mobile service console log:

```
The request 'GET /tables/Products?userID=xxxxxxxxx&gender=x' has timed out. This could be caused by a script that fails to write to the response, or otherwise fails to return from an asynchronous call in a timely manner.
```

How can i optimize this command ? or can you suggest me another approach ?

Thank you

Comment: What about indexes? Have you any on these tables? Also statement like `not in (huge_list)` doesn't seems like a good idea. Use join instead.

Comment: Please provide your execution plan (`*.sqlplan`)

Comment: @AndyKorneyev no i dont have any indexes on these tables i am looking right now and thank you for your suggestion to use joins instead of not in

Comment: @Devart i will get the sqlplan and edit question , due to the reason i am using azure mobile service i dont touch the sql diagram much but i guess i need to touch on these too

Comment: 1) `not exists()` 2) indexes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this query:

```
select TOP 50 p.*
from products p
where p.id not in (select product_id from products_log pl where pl.user_id = ?) and
      p.gender in (?, 2)
order by newid();
```

You can first try indexes:  `products(gender, id)`, `products_log(user_id, gender, product_id)`.

You might also try phrasing this as a `not exists` or `left join`:

```
select TOP 50 p.*
from products p left join
     products_log pl 
     on p.id = pl.product_id and pl.user_id = ? and 
where p.gender in (?, 2) and pl.product_id is null
order by newid();
```

For this query, the appropriate indexes are `products(gender, id)` and `products_log(product_id, user_id)`.

Note: if the query (without the `top`) is returning many, many rows, then the `order by` is dominating the time.  If so, you'll need an alternative method for getting 50 random rows.